# Android Content Provider and App in One APK?

Tags: android, apk, android-contentprovider

I am creating an Android app that will get data from the Internet.  Eventually I will want to change the app to get similar data from a different (yet to be determined) Internet location.  Then even later, yet another location.  I'd like to avoid changing my app to account for different Internet locations because that would be difficult to maintain.

There's probably a lot of options, but after some research it seems like a Content Provider may do what I want.  It looks like Content Providers were designed to expose data across application boundaries.  This is okay, but I don't care that the Content Provider is in a different app from my main app.  No other app would be interested in my Content Provider's data, so crossing application boundaries isn't helpful in this case.

- Is a Content Provider a good way to approach the problem?
- Is there another option I'm not considering?
- If a Content Provider is a good solution, how would I go about packaging both the app and the Content Provider(s) into a single .apk file?
- Can this be done inside Eclipse or do I need to use the command line tools?

Comment: I have a series of customers that each want their own unique data source for an app customized for their business.  The maintenance issue is that I need to keep one source and then select a plugin module that customizes the data showing only the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

Content provider is a good solution for your problem.

You just have to declare your content provider in your manifest and it's build with your apk. If you don't declare your Content provider as publi, only your app can access to your data.

A good lib/sample for beginning with content Providers is data droid http://datadroid.foxykeep.com/ It will do all the stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the data directly in a ListView for example, it might be beneficial to create a content provider.

You could also opt for a different abstraction within your app, for example a new class that abstracts out the different sources. I don't really see the argument for using a content provider just to make your app more maintainable.

You might even argue that a content provider adds more complexity while you are not using most of it's features.

If you do go for a content provider you can add it to your main app as a component by declaring it in AndroidManifest.nl just fine and you can develop and package the app in Eclipse like you would normally.

Comment: Right, in that case there could be a valid point for a content provider. You just make the base app and several content provider apps in Eclipse. The content provider apps just won't have any activities in it and only the content provider in AndroidManifest.xml. Note that you could only install one content provider because the uri it uses must be unique. And you would need to install 2 apps: base + content provider of choice.